# SpringBoot 2.x Spring 5.x Oauth 2.0 Spring security Bitbucket integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I was going over the article on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login and was trying to add my custom providers and was stuck with bitbucket.org.

I am exploring the integration with bitbucket.org (https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication) I am unable to figure out the user-info endpoint for bitbucket and thought if you can help me in getting the info.

Here is my example application.yml

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${GOOGLE_SECRET}
          github:
            client-id: ${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${GITHUB_SECRET}
          bitbucket:
            client-id: ${BIT_BUCKET_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${BIT_BUCKET_SECRET}
            client-authentication-method: post
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            client-name: BitBucket
          linkedin:
            client-id: ${LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${LINKEDIN_SECRET}
            scope: r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress
            client-authentication-method: post
            authorization-grant-type: implicit
            redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            client-name: Linkedin
        provider:
          bitbucket:
            authorization-uri: https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token
            user-info-uri: https://bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
            user-name-attribute: id
          linkedin:
            authorization-uri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
            token-uri: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
            user-info-uri: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json
            user-name-attribute: id
```

Any assistance on this will be of great help.

I am getting the below error:

```
2018-12-26 12:20:29.492 DEBUG 16494 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: 403 Forbidden

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_user_info_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: 403 Forbidden
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService.loadUser(DefaultOAuth2UserService.java:126) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java:116) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:186) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) [spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:83) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler.java:52) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService.loadUser(DefaultOAuth2UserService.java:108) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Logs says: `An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the UserInfo Resource: 403 Forbidden`

Thats not always about not having access, sometime it means something is wrong with user info endpoint,having that missconfigured and calling wrong endpoint might endup with getting this error.

For me this config line looks suspicious:
`user-info-uri: https://bitbucket.org/user/repo.git`

I found following example: https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-bitbucket/blob/master/src/Provider/Bitbucket.php

And they are using `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user`

Comment: Please include relevant code in your answer, as links may go stale, or their content may be changed in the future, invalidation your answer.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I've been referencing php project, and issue we are talking about is pure configuration so I believe it is sufficient to post only value they used for user info url configuration (what I've posted)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to the OP but I've came here looking for a similar problem when trying to use Gitlab instead. I got the same error and was able to resolve it by adding openid and read_user to the scopes.

You can easily check if the user-info-uri is correct by simply visiting it. I found that the uri was correct but somehow still returned a 403. After reading carefully about the scopes on gitlab I figured I did not have the permission to access the user info :-)

Here is my oauth spring config for gitlab:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gitlab:
            client-id: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}
            scope: openid,read_user,read_api
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/gitlab
            client-name: GitLab.com
            provider: gitlab
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        provider:
          gitlab:
            authorization-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://gitlab.com/oauth/discovery/keys
```